# I can see my .scss files in the Dev Tools, but not in my text editor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, templates, sass, text-editor

I am using a Bootstrap template to work on a project. I have noticed that when I open the template index.html file, I can see more folders in my scss folder. However, when in my text editor(VSC), I can only see a certain number of scss files. 
Does anyone know what could be causing this? 
I am able to make temporary changes in the browser, but I cannot save my changes because the files does not appear in my VSC. 
I inserted screenshots of my problem below. The first image is from the Dev tools in the browser, and the second image is what I see in my test editor. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVtGK.png) . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKVtZ.png)

Comment: previewing some source code can help resolve this, for instance does your index.html reference any external files from a cdn?

Answer (score 2):

In order to provide a more detailed solution I would have to see which "template" you are using. Is this based on an [official Bootstrap theme](https://themes.getbootstrap.com/) or a 3rd party theme?

Chrome developer tools uses source mapping, so if a sass file references 3rd party code like `@import npm_modules/bootstrap/_alerts.scss` then it will follow the path and show the referenced file.

It appears that the first image (chrome developer tools) is referencing the downloaded Bootstrap source code that was packaged with your template. If that's the case you can do a [global search in VSC](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files) to find the files.

Once you find the original file you should import it into your `_bootstrap-overrides.scss` file instead of editing the template's original source code.